# Eclipse POM XML Autoformat removing newlines

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven

I have recently upgraded my Eclipse IDE and noticed that manually added newlines are removed when running the auto-formatter (CTRL+Shift+F) in pom.xml files.

I did not find any option in the settings to prevent this behaviour. Is it possible to switch back to the old behaviour somehow? I want automatic indentation correction but my files should still be structured with newlines.

**Update: The issue only happens in the pom.xml editor tab of Maven Pom Editor.**

An option to work around this is now to just open the file in the regular xml editor view.

I'm using: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

Comment: Might be worth raising an Issue with https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens because of a regression in the WWD formatting settings.

After updating WWD to the latest snapshot (*Wild Web Developer XML tools    1.0.2.202301161637*) using the update site the issue was gone.

Update Site:

- http://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots

After Update the following setting can be found:

> XML -> Formatting -> Preserve new lines that seperate tags. (Default: 2)